# How to render a view in the controller and assign into a variable (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following view code:

**app/views/calendars/try.html.erb**

```
<%= @ow %>
```

Then in my controller, I have the following:

**app/controllers/calendars_controller.rb**

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
  def try
    @ow = 'hello'
  end
end
```

The thing is, I want to get the content of the view file and assign it to a variable in the **controller**.

Something like `myvar = content_of_my_view` then `myvar` will return `hello`.

Is it possible to do it like this?

I have tried the following:

**Test 1:**

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
  def try
    @ow = 'hello'

    html = open(Rails.root.join('app','views','calendars','try.html.erb')).read

    raise html.inspect
  end
end
```

This will return `<%= @ow %>` as a plain text not `hello` just I want it to be.

**Test 2:**

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
  def try
    @ow = 'hello'

    html = open(File.join('app','views','calendars','try.html.erb')).read

    raise html.inspect
  end
end
```

Same output in **Test 1**.

**Test 3:**

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
  def try
    @ow = 'hello'

    html = open(Rails.root.join('app','views','calendars','try.html.erb'), 'rb') {|io| a = a + io.read}

    raise html.inspect
  end
end
```

Same output in **Test 1** and **Test 2**.

**Test 4:**

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
  def try
    @ow = 'hello'

     html = IO.binread(Rails.root.join('app','views','calendars','try.html.erb'))

    raise html.inspect
  end
end
```

Same output in **Test 1**, **Test 2**, and **Test 3**.

**Test 5:**

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
  def try
    @ow = 'hello'

     html = render('o')

    raise html.inspect
  end
end
```

This will return nothing.

Is it possible to return it as `hello` from the controller? I can't seem to find a way to render the variable and not print it as a plain text.

Comment: Why do you need to assign the html in the controller? It seems to violate the whole concept of MVC

Comment: I have a view, a template rather that I want to call in the controller. Then I will assign its HTML content in a variable then render/export it as pdf.

Comment: Actually I can write the HTML code directly in the controller, I just want to make it more clean by writing the HTML in the view rather in the controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [render_to_string](https://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/render_to_string) to render an ERB template and return its contents as a string.

Comment: Okay so I got it using the following code: `html = render_to_string(:partial => 'o.html', :format => :html)`. I created another partial for me to render. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The friendliest way to do this in Rails 5 is to use the [`ActionController::Renderer` API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderer.html):

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
  def try
    html = CalendarsController.render(
      template: "calendars/try.html.erb",
      assigns: {
        ow: "hello",
      },
    )
  end
end
```

Note that it builds a separate controller instance, so it doesn't have access to your local instance variables: they must instead be passed in explicitly as `assigns`. (Though you could of course use `{ ow: @ow }` if you need it in both places.)

Comment: This does work also, but I prefer the shorter code, and you came a little too late. Will give an upvote for appreciation. Thank you.